# Unable to loop video file using embed tag in firefox

Tags: html, ubuntu-14.04, mozilla

Video file embedded in an html-page using the 'embed' tag never play the video in loop, even if the 'loop' value is kept as 'true'.

Sample Code is as below

```
<embed src="http://.../MyVideo2.avi" id="theVideo" width="320" height="250" CONTROLLER="true" loop=true PLAYCOUNT=3 AUTOPLAY="false" name="IBM Video1" align="left" top=100px ></embed>
```

I tried to add another variable PLAYCOUNT also. But that too in vain.Im am running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried `<video>` instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: I wanted to embed '.avi' file, which is not possible via <video> tag. Anyway I have already tried using <video> tag with '.mp4' file and was able to loop the video file